# Can a meromorphic function $f:U \to \mathbb{C}, \; U\subset \mathbb{C}$ domain, that is not the zero function, have a zero of order infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Can a meromorphic function $f:U \to \mathbb{C}, \; U\subset \mathbb{C}$ domain, that is not the zero function, have a zero of order infinity?

(Clear: Would $f$ be holomorphic on the whole domain U then there is no zero of order infinity if $f\neq 0$)

Comment: The power series at that value would converge to $f$ in some non-trivial ball and equal zero. If $f$ is meromorphic and zero on an infinite  compact set, it is zero everywhere.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews From what follows that a meromorphic function that is zero on an infinite compact set is zero everywhere? Is this a known theorem?

Comment: I forget the theorem's name, but it is certainly a common result in any first year complex analysis. It's one of the most important things about complex analysis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Do you mean the identity theorem? But this holds for holomorphic functions on a domain. So if $U$ is a domain and $f$ is meromorphic on $U$, then $f$ is only holomorphic on $U\setminus S$, where $S$ is the set of poles and $U \setminus S$ doesn't have to be a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since zeros of a meromorphic function are isolated (cf. [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles#Definitions)), we can restrict $U$ to a small ball $B$ on which $f$ is holomorphic. Then, as **Thomas Andrews** pointed out in the comments, the [identity theorem implies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) that an infinite order zero can only occure for the 0-function on $B$. By [analytic continuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) $f$ was zero on all of $U$.

Nonzero meromorphic $f$ thus connot have zero of infinite order.